# Offer a 'homework' tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, meta-tags

S.O. (and perhaps other sites) should offer a [homework] tag that means "I'm asking this question because I have it as a homework problem".

With this, clueless newbies -- I mean *seekers of enlightenment* -- can be honest about their motivation for posting the question.

And the homework tag should come with the guarantee that if you use it, you won't get hassled for asking.

Comment: But how would newbies know about this "homework" tag?

Comment: Bad questions aren't ok just because they are homework.

Comment: Hey, it's the `[homework]` meta-tag again! [Long time no see, `[homework]` meta-tag.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/164403)

Comment: The biggest problem with homework questions is that are almost always asked by those who haven't read the "How to ask?" help. If I see a poor non-specific question that has been favourited it's like an alarm beacon that the asker and other students on the same course are circling homework help vampires.

Comment: Been there, done that.

Comment: so..... if there's a new guy who comes in, copies the question from his assignment, and tags it as homework, it makes it OKAY for us not to harass him? I hope this isn't serious...

Comment: "clueless newbies -- I mean seekers of enlightenment" That attitude is a problem. Nobody is a "clueless newbie", that is inherently insulting. Nobody starts with an ingrained knowledge of programming.

Comment: Racking up -14 points on what was intended as a lighthearted question is a personal record!  :)  On the other hand, I should have done my (ahem) homework, in which case I would have seen this path has already been trodden and found wanting.  Thanks all for the education.

Comment: A little history you may not be aware of: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What problem does this really solve? If you have a good question that isn't a duplicate, just ask it. It doesn't matter if it was assigned as homework or not. We had the homework meta tag before and it added no real value. Ultimately, we decided to burninate it.

See [Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) and [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) for details.

Comment: Here's the problem I've seen: a newcomer asks a question which smells like a homework problem. The answer may be obvious to anybody who has been programming for a while.  But rather than getting thoughtful answers, the newcomer is unjustly castigated for asking a simple question.  But if this path has been tried, I say simply let it go.

Comment: @fearless_fool The `homework` tag didn't do much to alleviate that problem. Most of the time I see that happen is when someone copy/pastes their homework and that's it. The best way to avoid a bad reaction is for the OP to post the code they've tried, and ask a specific question about where they are stuck. Simply tagging a question `homework` isn't enough effort.