# Is it okay to create a tag based on a user name?

Tags: discussion, tags, users

The following question contains a tag with the username [jonskeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jonskeet), the tag refers to the [top ranked user in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) :

[Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification)

Some users in [the post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2550925/revisions) removed the tag and others added it.

Are tags with users names allowed / normal or should they be removed?

Comment: The "Jon Skeet should be a Tag" comment on that question just comes off as childish to me. There are places for meme circlejerking, and tags are not one of them. Good on you for bringing this to meta, because meta is exactly where this sort of thing should be discussed. Not by perpetuating a years-old edit war.

Comment: @Jongware Jon Skeet is a normal user and no, he should not be removed. Also, he is quite a famous user who has contributed immensely, and literally helped millions of visitors. Also, the tag jonskeet is totally useless and should be burninated and locked from ever using again.

Comment: "Jon Skeet is a normal user" nice try "Jon Skeet" / skynet

Comment: Burninate Jon Skeet? Ouch..

Comment: @Jongware To be fair, Knuth is a well-known name in most programming circles and his works are taught in universities worldwide. As amazingly knowledgeable as Jon Skeet is, I've never heard his name mentioned outside of Stack Exchange, with a few exceptions.

Comment: what to do with [tag:gnat] tag? as of now, it has 154 questions

Comment: ...I think it's a [bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnat)

Comment: I think it's fine. Once Jon Skeet creates the ultimate programming language (called JonSkeet), then the tag will exist anyway. It will become so ubiquitous that JS will no longer be synonymized with Javascript.

Comment: @MageXy you can't just say that and *not* tell us about those exceptions!

Comment: This meme is pretty childish anyway. Can't we get over it already? It's been six years.

Comment: That post is really ill-named. If we all named our design-patterns it would be a truly confusing world.  "How to implement a 'Static-Singleton'", is far more contextual and informative (I can even work out what it does from the name).

Comment: Never though my "Jon Skeet should be a Tag" comment was going to have any impact, it was more like a joke, sorry. But it was because many times I've found myself in the situation of remembering that Jon has responded something wonderfully, and it would have been easier to find those answers by having that Tag.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, not really okay.

At least since it was Jon Skeet it was *understandable*, but really there is no reason to have that tag. Just as there is no reason to have an Apress (popular book publisher) tag for example; or a reddit tag for explaining issues found from reddit; or a *homework* tag for issues found in homework.

Tags should represent the actual issue presented, not the source of where it was found.

Comment: a `homework` tag would at least be honest...

Comment: @flaschbier [lets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277880/offer-a-homework-tag?s=1|2.9893) [not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308250/add-a-policy-and-a-tag-for-self-study-homework?s=2|1.0384) [start](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag?s=3|0.3496) [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277880/offer-a-homework-tag/277881?s=4|0.3446#277881) again.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid [ACK](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACK_%28Signal%29)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't want to _"start that again"_ but a `homework` tag would help us to find _"pliz help me with my homework"_-questions faster XD

Comment: Are you saying the [tag:knuth] tag mentioned above should be removed too?

Comment: @svick - It doesn't seem to add much, only 50 questions, each of which is only answerable if presenting the actual issue and not the source. However, I am not saying that tag should be removed, we could have a separate conversation on that if you wish. My assumption would be that it remains, but historically that type of tag has been removed and returned as borderline. So I could see it being removed only to return. The real question I have for you is, how did that tag make those questions more answerable? In its absence, could those questions be answered without it?