# Should homework questions disclose that they are homework questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, homework

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) on "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)" had an accepted top community wiki answer from the beginning (Oct 23 '08) that said:

> - **Admit that the question is homework.** Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster. [Do not use a “homework” tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag), but mention it in the question text if relevant (you can structure your question this way: “How can I do …? I'm trying to do this as part of … which is a homework problem. This is my attempt so far: …”).

This paragraph was removed in [r8](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/8) and promptly [restored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/9) by the person who wrote the answer originally.  This was [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/11) again months later when a different editor removed that paragraph along with another edit and again [restored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/12) by the original author.  The same editor pair [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/15) and [restored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/16) the content an additional time, and then another editor [removed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/17).  Other edits followed, with discussion focused on other points, like if the FAQ content should [avoid summarizing points from elsewhere on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376344/798371) because they could be found elsewhere.  This paragraph got removed without substantive discussion on this point.

When it was [restored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/23) (because there had not been substantive discussion or consensus on this point), it was quickly [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/24) with the edit comment

> There is no such rule. We do not *create* new rules in community wikis. We add them if they exist. If you think there should be such a rule please start a discussion first.

So apparently we remove longstanding rules without discussion, even if they have stood in the FAQ on the topic for years and resisted prior removal, but we don't restore content that was disturbed during unrelated editing without being accused of creating new rules.

In later discussion on a different meta topic, a user who disagreed with that point [repeatedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction/376345?noredirect=1#comment644946_376345) [claimed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction/376345?noredirect=1#comment644979_376345):

> You can see that there has been a long consensus that whether or not a question is related to a homework problem is irrelevant to the question...whether homework questions need to be marked as such has been discussed *to death* and the consensus came to be that homework questions should be treated as any other type of question, and not marked as such.

This meta question is intended to serve as a focal point for that discussion that has allegedly long happened but could not be linked to, beyond discussion of using a tag which was already linked to in the original paragraph giving a different rule about admitting the question is homework.

**Should homework questions admit that they are homework?**

*Note: By asking this question, I am not intending to imply a position either way, but I am intending to start the discussion instead of having to argue about whether or not such a discussion exists and has long ago reached the opposite conclusion to the one that stood for many years in the highly-upvoted FAQ for the topic, and was removed without substantive discussion on that point.*

Comment: I'm not sure how continually referring to the original author strengthens your case; it's a community wiki, so the original author has no greater say than anyone else when it comes to edits.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree but in now-deleted comments there, some people thought it made a difference.  I therefore included the information for those readers who do think it's relevant, as others can ignore that information.

Comment: I think leaving it in weakens your case; it's an appeal to authority that doesn't exist.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not trying to make a case here.  I'm trying to open a space for community discussion about a specific point, and provide background which some people think is relevant for that discussion.

Comment: Based on the tone and slant of your meta posts here, I disagree with that assertion.  I think you *are* making a case.  They don't sound at all neutral.

Comment: Of course, it's okay to not be neutral and to have an opinion on a topic, even when starting a discussion on it.  It's just that claiming you have no position and that you're being neutral falls rather flat when your posts and wording show a very clear bias to one view.  Just be open about what your opinion is.  People can then agree or disagree with it.  It's how discussions on meta generally go.

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to say I don't appreciate being falsely accused of creating a new rule when I was intentionally trying to avoid disturbing something that stood for years.  I think somebody else should have opened this discussion years ago and that if people are going to claim strong consensus they should be able to point to a discussion to back it up.  I'm not a fan of unfounded claims of consensus like that.  Personally, I see merit on both sides and I think the FAQ should reflect community consensus if one exists.  If it does, it should become clear below.

Comment: @WBT Well, you weren't falsely accused of trying to create new rules, the accusation was just erroneously pointed at the wrong change that you made, of the several improper changes that you made.  It's an understandable mistake, but still a mistake.

Comment: @WBT Also, you *were* linked to posts stating the consensus is that that doesn't belong in the question.  You just didn't like them.  You can't say people can't, or didn't, provide you with sources, when they both can, and did.

Comment: @Servy Where were those posts? There were a couple comments.  If there's been a consensus established, I believe it should be linked to from that FAQ (and right here in comments), just like there was a link to the discussion about not using a homework tag.  Whether or not that tag point matters now that it's been burninated may be a different discussion on relevance, after [establishing whether or not relevance is the applicable decision rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction) compared to existence elsewhere on meta.

Comment: @WBT Given that the comments are deleted, I couldn't say why no one linked to past discussions there (or even whether anyone did).  Did you ask if there were discussions on the topic, given how opposed you are to it being removed?

Comment: @Servy I tried to focus that discussion on the substantive edits I was trying to make; I agree that if another point is going to be changed there should be on-topic discussion on it.  Here's a space for that discussion.  My main point is that we shouldn't make a significant change to a long-standing rule stated in an FAQ without specific discussion, especially when there is apparently disagreement about it.

Comment: @WBT So then you have your answer for why no one was linking you past discussions of this topic in the FAQ, you didn't ask.  Now you've duplicated it and we've had the discussion *yet again*.  As you were told in your last meta post, people don't need to make a meta question before every single change to an FAQ.  Someone removed something because the FAQ had a statement that wasn't in line with well established guidelines.  That's perfectly fine.  If people disagree that it was correct *then* a discussion can take place, if the earlier discussions were inadequate.

Comment: @Servy I started the discussion because I had repeatedly requested and looked for where the discussion allegedly happened before, and couldn't get an answer on that.  If you're going to assert that the discussion happened and consensus was reached, you should be able to point to the discussion which backs that up.  If you think it's a duplicate, what do you think it's a duplicate of?

Comment: @WBT I did link you to a discussion stating that there is no need for homework questions to disclosed that they're homework questions, and it had a duplicate it was linked to, and several other questions in comments and in the answer, all on the topic.

Comment: @Servy The question you linked to focused on tagging.  Whether or not there should be a homework tag seems fairly well resolved and there's a link to a relevant discussion.  Even in light of that, the FAQ still stated the opposite conclusion about whether or not questions should disclose that they're homework.  I didn't think that should be ripped out without discussion on that point specifically.  I didn't think discussion about a tag covered it, because of the explicit distinction in the long-standing text.

Comment: @WBT The *numerous* discussions linked all say that whether a question is a homework problem or not is irrelevant, and doesn't belong in the question.  They weren't saying that there should be no homework tag but that every single homework question must say, in the question, that it's homework.  They said that the homework tag doesn't exist *because questions should not be indicating whether they're homework or not* because it's just noise.

Comment: You keep saying things like "numerous discussions linked" and claim a longstanding overwhelming consensus.  Please **actually link** to the discussions you're claiming, and **not** discussions about tagging, in your next comment.  The point in the FAQ *acknowledged* the discussion about not tagging and claimed a need for disclosure even considering that.  Show me a discussion that focuses on disclosure specifically, if you think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @WBT I linked you to it in your previous meta post, you've been given links in the answer. You can't type "homework" in the search bar without finding a dozen posts on the subject.  That one person kept reverting the FAQ when it was changed because that *one person* didn't like the well agreed on consensus doesn't make them right.

Comment: @Servy *I linked you to it in your previous meta post* You repeatedly made assertions but did not actually provide that link, despite repeated requests.  You only linked to one post about a homework **tag**.  The FAQ point acknowledges there shouldn't be a tag and links to a discussion to back that up, but still says the question should admit that it's homework despite that content, and that stood for many years. This discussion is about that non-tag admission that a question is homework. If consensus is reached here, any "one reverter" will be more easily overruled.

Comment: @WBT I linked you to posts that specifically said that it's not appropriate for a question to state whether or not it's homework, and that it's noise.  Thus, that's demonstrating that the statement that "all homework questions must state that they are homework" is not in line with the community consensus.  The questions aren't *just* about the homework tag.  Again, they're not all saying, "Don't use the homework tag, but never forget to mention that a problem is homework".  If they did, you would have a point.

Comment: @WBT That other posts also mention that the homework tag doesn't exist *because it's specifically policy that homework questions shouldn't mention that they're homework* doesn't make them off topic in a question about whether posts should indicate that they're homework.  In fact, it makes them *a dead on answer*.  But hey, you wanted to create *yet another duplicate*.  Congrats.  You succeeded.  Surprisingly, nothing changed, and you succeeded in getting a bunch of people to repeat, exactly, what was in the numerous duplicates you saw.

Comment: @Servy Where were those links you keep claiming? The FAQ **did** say essentially "Don't use the homework tag, but never forget to mention that a problem is homework." Its author was clearly not ignorant of discussions about not having the homework tag, and at least some people are making distinctions between a tag and statement in the question.  Therefore, here's a discussion about whether homework questions need to be disclosed as such in the statement of the question.  If you think it's a duplicate, I challenge you to provide the specific link of what you think it's a duplicate of.

Comment: Good faith can only go so far.  All this obstinance and pedantry on requiring a link makes it look like you're trying to push an agenda.  For me, the links provided, both here *and* in your previous question were enough.  Making a distinction between tag discussions and actual site policy is playing with semantics, and doesn't move the discussion forward at all.

Comment: @fbueckert It's because Servy keeps making assertions claiming backing of community consensus and discussions that apparently don't exist. Servy claims to have provided links to those discussions that weren't about the tag, but actually didn't.  I don't want people making wrong conclusions about asserted history.

Comment: And again, all this insistence on what the author wants or does makes zero sense.  Who cares!?  It's literally irrelevant to the current situation.

Comment: @fbueckert Servy cares about exactly who is doing what.  So does Makoto, below.  That's who cares.

Comment: And, yes, [he did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction#comment645001_376345).  Semantics and pedantry notwithstanding.

Comment: @fbueckert As I acknowledged, that discussion is about *Offer[ing] a 'homework' tag*.  The point in the FAQ acknowledged consensus against doing that.  The longstanding FAQ distinguished between that and acknowledging that it's homework in the text of the question.

Comment: I repeat: semantics and pedantry notwithstanding.  Also, he [offered a search term](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction#comment644951_376345) which provides *way* more info.  Either way, though, I don't think you're discussing in good faith, so I'll content myself with observing that behaviour, disagree with your case and downvote, and let someone else continue the argument.

Comment: @fbueckert I did that search, way before any of this.  I found questions about the tag, about duplicate homework problems, about general low quality of homework questions, etc., but couldn't find a discussion on this particular point.  Meta is huge and it's possible I've missed something, but I would really appreciate someone specifically pointing to what they think this question is a duplicate of if it is indeed a duplicate, and having that question not be about tagging which the FAQ clearly distinguished for years.

Comment: @WBT You can't just say, "Other questions discussing whether or not homework questions should mention that they are homework also discussed the tag, so everything they say is off topic and it doesn't matter that *every single one of them says that homework questions should not mention in any way that they are homework as it's off topic.*"  That's just nonsense.  The posts specifically say that it's irrelevant to a question whether it's homework or not.  That's why there's no tag, that's why there's no disclosure in the question.  It's all the same issue.

Comment: The reason I rolled it back was that a significant chunk of text was removed. Had you simply edited the bit about homework back in, I wouldn't have thought to roll it back.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The removed license text was, in my view, less relevant than the more relevant points TinyGiant had removed. TinyGiant generally held that [information should not be on the FAQ if it can be found elsewhere on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376344/798371), & inconsistently claimed only formal, non-etiquette, requirements were admissible for FAQ, with trolling-like behavior changing positions just to be contrary. r22 seemed like it was just an over-the-top edit to include less relevant points in an argumentative move of pushing the found-elsewhere point too far.

Comment: @Servy Then despite those discussions on the topic of the tag, why was it so clearly distinguished for so many years in an FAQ answer that got so much attention? My main point here is that a longstanding stated rule should not be removed without a specifically on-point community discussion reaching consensus. For many years tag & text were distinct points with opposite answers about what people were supposed to do on homework ?s. Feel free to put relevant points from those other discussions in answers, but recognize the distinction has stood for a while & should have discussion before removal.

Comment: @WBT Apparently no one noticed.  Like I've said before, the FAQs aren't kept nearly as up to date as you seem to think they should be.  That, and the fact that one person who disagrees with the consensus kept rolling back changes to it when others would fix it to be in line with the community consensus. You keep saying discussion was needed to remove it but *there were dozens of discussions on the topic*. There wasn't one person changing established policy without it being discussed, rather it was one person *reverting the changes every time someone brought it in line with established policy*.

Comment: It wasn't just one person, and it did stand untouched for many years, only to be pulled out as collateral changes during disagreement over other unrelated edits, without the on-point discussion that seems appropriate for such a change in announced rules.  If this discussion existed, someone could point to that as justification for leaving it in or out and I think that would be respected.  Now the discussion does exist, and when it settles down it can be used for that purpose.

Comment: @WBT It was one person and you.  I omitted saying that you also reverted it because I presume you know that you also reverted it once.  I linked to you of a discussion which itself links to 5 other discussions on the topic.  I would think **six** different discussions all saying that homework questions should not indicate that they are homework problems would be enough for you. If it's not, how many discussions on the topic, all supporting the same conclusion, do you need for it to be enough for you to not revert the edit?  Why is you duplicating the discussion *yet again*, helpful?

Comment: @WBT Just repeating over and over again that no one has ever discussed whether or not homework questions should be marked as homework, and when you've seen *multiple* examples yourself, doesn't make it true.  It's been proven demonstrably false, many times, that this has been discussed, and even that you knew about those discussions before duplicating it by posting this question.

Comment: I've undeleted the comments and move them to [a chat under the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#comment645356_334823) so people can see clearly what was said.

Comment: @Servy Again, what you linked to focused on the use of a **tag.** The FAQ clearly distinguished disclosure in the question text from use of a tag.  While some of the reasoning and points from those other discussions are relevant and should be brought in below (except that you below assume/enforce a rule that no one can bring in those arguments without personally thinking they are the best arguments), the point is clearly distinguished and the relevant discussion should focus on that point instead of a closely related but apparently distinct one.

Comment: @WBT No, those discussions are *not* exclusively about the tag.  The discussions say that it's not appropriate for questions to disclose that they're homework.  They don't say, "Questions must disclose that they're homework but we shouldn't have a tag."  Nor did they say, "Homework questions shouldn't use the tag but I'm not commenting on whether or not they should disclose that they're homework."  The fact that they mentioned the homework tag when saying that homework questions shouldn't disclose **in any way** that they're homework, doesn't make them irrelevant.  Repeating them isn't useful.

Comment: Response [below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376394/should-homework-questions-disclose-that-they-are-homework-questions/376395?noredirect=1#comment645493_376395) incorporated here by reference.

Comment: *I don't have a link to do that!* @WBT Scroll down to the bottom of the [chat page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/); there is a link to create a chat room. Leaving comments on your question instead of yivi's answer doesn't require a link.

Answer (score 28):

### No, they shouldn't.

What the answer is going to be used for is mostly noise, unless it's directly related to the question.

We don't care if the asker works at NASA or McDonalds. It's not important if this is their first job or if they are still studying.

What matters is that questions follow the site topicality rules, are properly scoped and clearly defined.

- On a good question, stating that it arises from a homework problem is noise at best, but most likely a distraction.
- On a bad question, it's an attempt to deflect criticism and judgement with information tangential to the question's quality and topicality.

We shouldn't encourage users to put irrelevant information in their posts, and we should edit it out if we encounter noisy posts.

Comment: I believe the contention here is the edit war and the subsequent lock on the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/334823/timeline)

Comment: @SurajRao No, the point of this discussion is the question posted above.  The other issue was about separate edits on other points.

Comment: @SurajRao I chose focus at the main point of the question. I do believe that the question could be improved upon by removing noise and backstory, but that's neither here nor there. :)

Comment: @WBT ok.. but the question itself focused on the arguments that occured in the edit war which led me to believe otherwise

Comment: @SurajRao The question included the history of edits to a post that was supposed to reflect community consensus.  To the extent that these changes reflect community consensus as they should, they may be relevant background to the discussion.  To the extent they do not, or to the extent they illustrate the presence of disagreement instead of the claimed overwhelming consensus, those history points should help demonstrate the value of starting a discussion on this specific point.

Comment: @WBT I think 5 users fighting in a massive rollback war doesn't indicate a lack of consensus In the *community*, but rather amongst *these five users* (I know my number isn't necessarily accurate, but you get my point I guess)

Comment: @Patrice <5 users vs. a point that has stood in a highly upvoted FAQ answer for about a decade? To me, that doesn't indicate the claimed overwhelming consensus on the side of the few users.

Comment: @WBT Did I say anything about that? All I said is that five users fighting on a FAQ isn't any indication of a community consensus or LACK of that consensus. It just shows that these five users aren't aligned. As soon as you posted a question for the whole community to see, that consensus was clear, and pointed to **numerous** other discussions that showed that consensus. Seriously, what more do you want? You are aware that the FAQ doesn't get reviewed by the full community everytime a single thing changes in it?

Comment: @WBT There was *one* user constantly rolling back the content, and you.  And since you claim (clearly in bad faith, but you have made the claim nonetheless) that you were just rolling it back because you think every single change to an FAQ should be rolled back unless there is a meta discussion about it, that leaves just *one* person constantly rolling back the changes.  Given that there are *dozens* of meta discussions on the topic, all with *very wide* agreement on the topic, one person constantly rolling it back (plus you) doesn't override that.

Comment: @Servy I was accused of creating a new rule without on-point discussion, by another user who didn't check the facts.  That's someone who thinks a rule change of this significance should have a specifically on-point discussion which did not then exist, AND that it's important to have such a discussion on that specific point before changes are made to the longstanding FAQ.  That rule stood for over a decade in a highly visible highly upvoted FAQ answer.  While I don't appreciate the false accusation, I agree with the principle behind the comment.  Hence, the existence of this discussion.

Comment: @Patrice You didn't claim overwhelming consensus. Servy did. The evidence claimed for this was a link to a discussion "Offer a 'homework' tag" linking to others like "Add a policy and a tag for self-study / homework," "Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?" and  "The homework tag is now officially deprecated."  The longstanding FAQ answer **very clearly** distinguished policy between use of a tag and disclosure in the question, acknowledging discussion around the tag and still reaching an opposite rule about text b/c tag discussion apparently doesn't cover that.

Comment: @WBT "I was accused of creating a new rule without on-point discussion" Which  you did, for the record.  It's not okay to edit an FAQ to suggest guidelines that aren't in line with other discussions.  The FAQ isn't the place to suggest new things, as you did.  Of course, the removal of the statement that homework questions must disclose that they're homework is not changing policy.  It has been long and well established policy that homework questions should not disclose that they're homework.  There was no need to discuss it *again* before changing the FAQ.

Comment: @WBT I linked to **numerous** discussions all saying that homework questions shouldn't disclose **in any way** that they're homework.  And that because of this, the homework tag was removed.  Those **numerous** discussions were ally *very* clear, with *overwhelming* support, that homework questions shouldn't disclose that they're homework *at all*, because it's noise, and that you should remove any reference to it from the question.  They're *exactly* on point, and demonstrate that the FAQ entry was specifically opposed to well established consensus.

Comment: @WBT where did I say I claimed community consensus? You're twisting (or reimagining) what I said...Again, you seem to say the fact it was in an FAQ means it was a rule, or that it indicated community consensus. **it didn't**, as all the discussions Servy shared with you (and I truly don't feel like rehashing those, **again**)

Comment: @WBT You can't just say, "Every single discussion only talked about the tag and none of them discussed disclosure in the question," when those discussions did in fact discuss disclosure in the question, and said that it's noise.  Your claim is simply *not true*.  Mentioning that there shouldn't be a tag *as well* doesn't change that.

Comment: @Servy I was **NOT** suggesting new things in the FAQ.  On this point, I was leaving content that had stood for a decade, intending to leave it undisturbed. Others were cutting it without reference to any on-point discussion. Evidence of your repeated misrepresentation of facts has been removed below, but as documented above I was **not** introducing content on this point. I was merely restoring what had stood as the stated rule for over a decade on the grounds such a change needed discussion first and I didn't see any that wasn't about the tag, which the FAQ point **clearly distinguished**.

Comment: I don't think it's worthwhile to continue this discussion, guys; it's clear there's not going to be any agreement.  Might be best to just let it lie and lets the votes do their thing.

Comment: @Servy In all your comments I find only that one link, not **numerous** links.  Even following links from that one I find a lot of discussion focused on the use of a tag.  The FAQ point **acknowledged** those discussions and set that as the summary rule **even considering the content discussed there** which would include general reasons that don't focus specifically on a tag.  You may disagree with the summary drawing that distinction but it stood for over a decade and got plenty of attention in that time.

Comment: @WBT You weren't suggesting new things to the FAQ by rolling back the removal of the statement that homework should be disclosed as such.  You *were* suggesting new things with your other edits to the FAQ to add in new guidelines.  Your rollback of a useful change to the FAQ to keep it in line with well established community consensus was wrong, but not the portion of your edits that was suggesting new things to the FAQ.

Comment: @Servy Those other edits were again not new content, and that was specifically why TinyGiant had such an issue with it: because it was [summarizing other points that could be found elsewhere on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376344/should-meta-faq-provide-a-summarizing-introduction#comment645001_376345), and that type of thing should NOT be in FAQ according to TinyGiant's repeated position.

Comment: @WBT There's one link that itself links to numerous other duplicate discussions on the topic, and  you can search for *dozens* more that have happened over the years.  You can trivially find them. I believe in your ability to search for the word "homework".  You're skilled enough to do it if the five discussions linked to you aren't enough.  The fact that the FAQ was wrong for several years doesn't mean no one is allowed to change it.  AS you've been told, the FAQs are *often* not as up to date as they should be.  That's not an argument for refusing to update them.

Comment: People, get a chatroom.

Comment: @Servy [I did search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376394/should-homework-questions-disclose-that-they-are-homework-questions/376395?noredirect=1#comment645135_376394).  It could be that the FAQ was wrong for years, but taking it out without reference to discussion that the FAQ itself didn't already clearly recognize and distinguish from that point doesn't seem to be the right way of going about fixing it.  Falsely accusing someone of creating a new rule when they're just restoring what's stood for over a decade seems like an even worse community process.

Comment: @WBT No, you were not specifically told that.  And now that the comments are public again, everyone can see that you were lying by claiming that you were told no meta post should ever duplicate content found elsewhere.  You were told that the content you added wrong, and you were also told that it was off topic in this post.  I'll quite Tiny's relevant comment below, but it very clearly states that what you added was off topic.  It said we shouldn't duplicate *everything* on meta in one post; it doesn't say no post should ever duplicate anything found elsewhere.

Comment: Tiny's *actual* quote is: "Again we don't need to sum up all of the content on meta and the help center in a single answer. We have meta and the help center for that. We can expect people to search meta if they have a question. We can't expect people to read a single post that tries to explain the entire system and all of its intricacies. Remember this question is "How do I ask and answer homework questions", so if we're going to include all of the information that might some day be of some relevance to askers and answerers, that would be everything that is on meta and in the help center."

Comment: @WBT We don't need to duplicate discussions that have taken place *dozens* of times with consistent, wide consensus on an answer just to change the FAQ to be in line with that consensus just because one person keeps rolling back the FAQ whenever it's updated to be in line with that consensus.  That's ridiculous.

Comment: @WBT But you weren't *just* restoring an incorrect statement in the FAQ that had been rolled back every time it had been corrected to be in line with consensus over the years, you *also* added in additional incorrect and off topic content to the FAQ.  It is *those* additions that make the accusation that you were attempting to create new rules a valid accusation.

Comment: @Servy When someone makes a substantive change a rule stated and standing for over a decade, they should point to a discussion indicating the consensus on the topic, and that pointer should NOT be to a discussion that was clearly considered and distinguished when that rule got written into the FAQ.  That step didn't happen. Ayhan underscored this principle along with a false accusation.

Comment: **GUYS**, yivi's likely getting massive pings from this and indicated they'd prefer not to.... do you mind moving this to the chat, or at least the Q, so Yivi's inbox isn't flooded....

Comment: @Patrice I don't have a link to do that!  Servy: Tiny knew that "everything that is on meta and in the help center" is a clear [over-exaggeration](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44519902#44519902) and that claim does not appear to have been made in good faith. Tiny was [clearly](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44519893#44519893) trying to go overboard with the suggestion of repeating everything instead of getting to the possibility of summing up the most relevant points, and misrepresnting the content of the edits.

Comment: @WBT Good thing there are *numerous* discussions on the topic that *specifically* discuss the point at and and very clear demonstrate that the claims that were altered were incorrect.  Also discussing additional points doesn't make them suddenly not apply.  Yes, Tiny's quote was an exaggeration.  And your claim that Tiny said that nothing should ever be duplicated on any post is simply a lie, because Tiny never said that.  Tiny said that you shouldn't duplicate content *that is off topic to the question*.

Answer (score 22):

## [We've been *over* this already.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354)

Every question on the site needs to be on-topic.  The only details that need to be included in the question are the details needed to define constraints on how the problem can be solved.  Labeling a question as "homework" only makes it easier for those who already have a dislike for homework questions to simply downvote and move on with their lives in spite of the fact that the question may be otherwise acceptable on the site.

---

I did jump in and [remove the language about the question needing to be homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/334823/17).  Why?

## Because it's *noise*!

It doesn't help you solve the problem.  It doesn't help you *define* the problem.  If the issue is that you don't necessarily like the question then we need to have a separate discussion about what questions we do and don't like here at Stack Overflow.

For the love of God, someone please remove the language about this already.  That part of the edit wasn't even *contested*...

Comment: It was contested...the removal of the content was reverted three times by the person who originally wrote that content.

Comment: @WBT Again, who wrote it, in a community wiki, is *irrelevant*.

Comment: @WBT:  Unless my search-fu is weaker than normal today, the only time it was contested was by *you*, in a rollback that should have never been done...

Comment: @Makoto The history of revisions to this point in the FAQ post is documented above.  Fbueckert: Clearly, someone cares about the identity of who's editing.

Comment: @Makoto One of the rollbacks that added that statement back in was WBT, 4 were Joel Coehoorn, one was Yvette.

Comment: @Servy:  I was looking at revisions 17+.

Comment: @Servy and I only restored it because I perceived a lack of on-point discussion supporting removal of a point that had stood for years.  My action on that point was motivated by process, with the same principle as ayhan's r24.  Once this discussion settles down, I would support whichever action is consistent with the consensus reached here.

Comment: On MathStackExchange I consider recommandable that homework questions be presented as such it is a straightforward helps to prevent entry-level questions to be solved with advanced techniques (i.e. a valid but unhelpful answer) and also helps making the answers useful for the original poster. On StackOverflow this seems to be a lesser problem, but I wouldn't like to see people trying to disguise questions that in the end are homework as if they weren't nor should valid questions be discouraged or hostilized.

Comment: Your claim (if I understood it properly) is that a homework tag would raise rejection, but there are moderation tools (such as flagging comments) to keep this problem in check. And regarding dislikes I think they're pretty much fair game.

Comment: @Mefitico: At a fundamental level, what's the difference between a homework problem and a practical problem?  Remember that not only is the world of math not the same as software engineering, so too is Math Overflow not the same as Stack Overflow.

Comment: Makoto: With a practical problem, frame challenges (e.g. 'use a `while` loop instead of a `for`'; 'use the language's built-in `sort()` instead of implementing your own') are more helpful answers than they are on homework problems with their artificial constraints. @Mefitico doesn't seem to be claiming SO and MO are equivalent, and the comment explicitly distinguishes between the sites, but also provides the background information and reasoning for whatever it may be worth in this discussion here.

Comment: In general, when programming professionally I need to achieve something which I can specify clearly once I reach "question level", and if if find a solution that works, I can often apply it without understanding it (though I'll usually take my time to understand the issue later). If I'm doing homework, then the understanding is the main goal and maybe a snippet of working code does not teach me what I need to know, the answer would benefit from more explanation and some guesswork on what are the shortcomings on my comprehension of the topic (my question itself may should be put into question).

Comment: Also, I was a preparatory course teaching assistant in the past (for math, physics, chemistry). Though "the answer" to the same question would always be the same, I would widely change my answer method and steps based on the student (do I know he comprehends the topic but missed a detail? Do I believe he actually needs a lecture on the topic before the question is approached? Does he know well the pre-requisites for a given topic?). Though indeed I was never a programming teacher.

Answer (score 8):

If the question is using material from someone other than the poster, it needs to properly reference it. This is just the [regular plagiarism policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

If the question has unusual constraints (e.g. "must use a `for` loop"), the reason why should be mentioned. If you don't mention this from the start, you'll probably be asked about it, since it's a key piece of information in deciding if a "frame challenge" answer (e.g. "use this `while` loop instead") would be acceptable.

I can't think of any other situation where you'd need to disclose the fact you're asking about homework (at least on Stack Overflow). In the end, it's just evaluated on whether it's a good question or a bad one and I think we'd all rather someone focus on the steps to making the question good.

Answer (score -18):

Disclosing that a question is homework helps potential answerers or commenters understand artificial constraints that the question presents, e.g. not being able to use a language's built-in `sort()` function.  Therefore, in questions with these sorts of artificial constraints, it can be helpful to explain the reasoning behind them.

Comment: _"understand artificial constraints that the question presents, e.g. not being able to use a language's built-in sort() "_ I would advise to just mention those constraints explicitly, possibly even including that it's, as already mentioned, an artificially unavoidable constraint. But hey, this still is not exactly, what was in that particular guideline: **admit that it's homework** suggests that one should always make it clear to everyone else that it is homework, even when that information is irrelevant.

Comment: Unless something is *physically* impossible in software, every constraint that exists is artificial.  You'd be surprised how often real-world problems get mistaken for homework problems.

Comment: @WBT So why not let people come to their own decisions, instead of saying "People will probably say this, so let me remind them that there are other options."? Does that not seem like something someone with a particular bias would do?

Comment: @EthanField The well-studied phenomena of groupthink leads people to overlook other options once they have found one that seems to have merit.  Balanced discussions often require someone stepping into the role of pointing out other options even if they are not personally convinced that those alternatives are the best option.

Comment: @EthanField Also, I didn't guess at which point "people will probably say" first.  I waited and when I saw only one side presented and starting to gain upvotes, I put in the other so they could both be considered.  As stated above, had this point been posted and started to gather votes first, I would have posted an answer like one of the others ("Every question on the site needs to be on-topic. The only details that need to be included in the question are the details needed to define constraints on how the problem can be solved. Unless it's relevant to defining the question, it's noise.")

Comment: @Ethan Field: Re-stating here an opinion others have made elsewhere does not equate to holding a personal stake in it. You can disagree with an opinion but respect it enough to consider it relevant to the conversation. It probably befits this answer to be a community wiki to drive home the point that WBT themself doesn't subscribe to the stated opinion.